# ¿Cómo puedo modificar un archivo de recursos en la aplicación distribuida en el cliente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mvc

Tengo varios archivos de recursos (`.resx`)  dependiendo del idioma, el cliente quiere cambiar la descripción a una entrada de su idioma en SU archivo, YO quiero hacerlo solamente en la aplicación que fue "deployada" en su empresa.

¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de trabajar el archivo de recursos para poder cambiarlos en el cliente?

Comment: Hola, puedes indicar qué tipo de aplicación es? Es ASP.NET? Es WindowsForms? Gracias

Comment: Creo que lo ideal sería que únicamente modifiques ese archivo en la aplicación de su empresa, finalmente solo se verá afectado ese cliente.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra supongo que por las etiquetas de [tag:mvc] y [tag:asp.net] debe ser una aplicación web :)

Comment: Pido disculpas por no haberme fijado mejor... :)

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, aunque nunca lo he hecho, diría que nada te impide edita el archivo `.resx` en cuestión con un editor de textos y modificar la descripción de la entrada. Más o menos, al editar el archivo verás algo así:

```html
<data name="variable" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Descripción a modificar</value>
```

Eso sí, si la aplicación se actualiza, ese valor volverá al que tengas en tu solución.

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, creo que como he solicitado, dependiendo del tipo de aplicación desarrollada, se realiza de diferente manera. En aplicaciones de escritorio deberá modificar el recurso y generar un [ensamblado satélite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/21a15yht(v=vs.110).aspx) que puede ser desplegado en la GAC. Si fuera una aplicación ASP.NET se puede modificar los archivos resx de las carpetas especiales en  App_GlobalResources, App_LocalResources. Pero ya veo en las etiquetas que la aplicacíón parece ser ASP.NET....

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra si efectivamente. Yo asumo que es ASP.NET fijándome en los tags

Comment: Aunque la aplicación se actualice, no necesariamente se deben reemplazar los archivos .resx, partiendo del hecho que no han sufrido moficiaciones mas que las solicitadas por el cliente :)

Comment: @Flxtr si tienes razon.Bueno, depende tambien de como se distribuya al servidor. Pero hay que contemplar la posiblidad ;)

Comment: Sí claro, aún hay muchas variables que tomar en cuenta, pero coincido, puede ser una solución muy viable :)

Comment: Estimados, es viable que mi aplicación **instalada en el cliente**, pueda editar el .resx?, como hago para que no se genere una Dll asociada a este? o, como hago para editar y volver a generar la "Dll" en el cliente?